# Perl - Parse multi-line data from a file with carriage return and line feed

Tags: regex, perl

```
ParseLog.log:

Bug : 4525: TC1 

Scan Summary:   

Affected Snap:

Snap data - Important Snap data 5674 

Stack data - Important Stack data 5421  

Affected Stack:

TestStream1 - Important Stack 6322

No Longer Affected Snap:

None

-------------

open(my $parseLog, '<', 'parseLog.log')   or die "Can't open search file: $!";    
local $/ = "\r\n" ; 

while ( my $line = <$parseLog> )
{

$line =~ s/[\x0A\x0D]//g;

my @bugData = $line =~ /Bug :(.*?):/g;
my @snapData = $line =~ /\bAffected Snap:\b(.*?)\bAffected Stack:\b/sg; 

print Dumper @bugData ;
print Dumper(@snapshotData);

}
```

From ParseLog.log, I would like to parse

1. Bug data (i.e.,4525 )
2. multiple line data between Affected Snap: and Affected Stack:

ParseLog files has carriage return and Line feed.

I am not able to remove them using chomp, so I've used `$line =~ s/[\x0A\x0D]//g;`

After this $line becomes

Bug : 4525: TC1Scan Summary:-------------Affected Snap:Snap data - Important Snap data 5674 Stack data - Important Stack data 5421
Affected Stack:TestStream1 - Important Stack 6322No Longer Affected Snap:None No Longer Affected Stack:None

I am able to parse Bug number(Bug : 4525: TC1)

When I try to parse "Affected Snap:", I get the following

```
$VAR1 = ' 4525';
$VAR1 = 'Snap data - Important Snap data 5674 Stack data - Important Stack data 5421';
```

**Expected:**

```
$VAR1 = ' 4525';
$VAR1 = 'Snap data - Important Snap data 5674';
$VAR1 = 'Stack data - Important Stack data 5421';
```

**Background:**

Files affected by bug 4525 are

"Snap data - Important Snap data 5674" and 
"Stack data - Important Stack data 5421"

Comment: Your variable names don't match. You have `@snapData` and `@snapshotData` in your example. The latter is never declared.

Comment: It's doing exactly what your code says. Taking everything after the text _Affected Snap:_. Please revise the expected and actual output to be the full Dumper output including the `$VAR1` and stuff. You can [edit] your question to add it.

Comment: If you're setting `$/` then `chomp` removes whatever you set it to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\R` stands for any kind of line break and you could use the flip-flop operator:

```
my @snapData;
while(<DATA>) {
    if (/^Affected Snap:/ .. /^Affected Stack:/) {
        s/\R+//;
        next if /^\s*$/;
        next if /^Affected /;
        push @snapData, $_;
    }
}
print Dumper\@snapData;



__DATA__
Affected Snap:

Snap data - Important Snap data  5674

Stack data - Important Stack data 5421


Affected Stack:

TestStream1 - Important Stack  6322
```

**Output:**

```
$VAR1 = [
          'Snap data - Important Snap data  5674',
          'Stack data - Important Stack data 5421'
        ];
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. 
"ParseLog.log" file also has data that contains sub string " Affected Snap". Please find the log below
Scan Summary:
-------------
Affected Snap:
Snap data - Important Snap data  5674    
Stack data - Important Stack data 5421
Affected Stack:
TestStream1 - Important Stack  6322
No Longer Affected Snap:
None
No Longer Affected Stack:
None

Comment: @Thanu: Please, edit your question and add a complete significant  example with expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the chomp command?

**CODE**

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
my @snapData;
while (<DATA>) {
    if (/^Affected Snap:/ .. /^Affected Stack:/) {
        chomp;
        s/\s+$//;
        next if /^\s*$/;
        next if /^Affected /;
        push @snapData, $_;
    }
}

print Dumper\@snapData;

__DATA__
ParseLog.log:

Bug : 4525: TC1 

Scan Summary:   

Affected Snap:

Snap data - Important Snap data 5674 

Stack data - Important Stack data 5421  

Affected Stack:

TestStream1 - Important Stack 6322

No Longer Affected Snap:

None
```

**Edit output**

```
$VAR1 = [
          'Snap data - Important Snap data 5674',
          'Stack data - Important Stack data 5421'
        ];
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming this is on a Unix/Linux system..

**A quick fix** that I use far too often is to `cat` the file with the CR+LF into a new file via the command line as shown here...

```
cat original.txt > fixed.txt
```

I'm not saying that this is the best way to fix this but at least this way the `^M` are all ignored by cat and not moved across into the fixed.txt file.

Then all you need to do is to parse the fixed.txt as you like.

Comment: The command you give does *absolutely nothing* to fix newlines; `fixed.txt` will just be an exact copy of `original.txt`.